# What is the lifespan of Skeletal Muscle Cells?

Tags: human-biology, cell-biology, physiology, human-physiology

I have read that skeletal muscle cells cannot multiply and are generally not created after early development. However, I have also read that they have a "lifespan" of 10-15 years. Could this lifespan actually be referring to the turnover rate of the ***majority of material*** in the cell, and that the ***literal lifespan*** of the cell (if we count all of its components, including the nucleus) would be the same as that of the owner?

Comment: This is a huge debate and I'm guessing you read the lifespan numbers in one of the papers arguing that there is a certain degree of myocyte turnover.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, it's nice to know at least some context on the question. It was getting very confusing reading articles that would make arguments with absolute certainty but not qualifying those statements with much specification!